# Yarn workspaces detects package but yarn workspace does not

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

`yarn workspaces info` lists 2 packages say `react-simple-boilerplate` and `website` but `yarn workspace react-simple-boilerplate build` says `unknown workspace "react-simple-boilerplate"`.

yarn version 1.22.4
node versions 14.4.0

Root package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "react-simple-boilerplate",
    "website"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "yarn workspace react-simple-boilerplate lint",
    "build": "concurrently 'yarn workspace react-simple-boilerplate build' 'yarn workspace website build'",
    "dev:boilerplate": "yarn workspace react-simple-boilerplate dev",
    "dev:website": "yarn workspace website dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

react-simple-boilerplate package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-simple-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react boilerplate with support for travis ci, webpack, sass etc.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:css && webpack ---config ./config/webpack.prod.config.js",
    "dev": "npm run watch:css && webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.config.js --open",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx src/",
    "lint:fix": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx src/ --fix",
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/css/styles.css -o src/assets/css/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/css/styles.css -o src/assets/css/main.css",
    "test": "cross-env jest --collect-coverage --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx}": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx src/ && cross-env jest --collect-coverage --env=jsdom"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "boilerplate",
    "webpack",
    "webpack hmr",
    "travis",
    "react-simple-boilerplate",
    "react-boilerplate"
  ],
  "author": "Uday Bhaskhar",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.3.4",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^25.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.10",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

website package.json

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "remark": "^12.0.0",
    "remark-html": "^11.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading yarn version to 1.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```bash
yarn policies set-version 1.19.0
```